# Add an "underline" to a box with CSS

Tags: css

I want to achieve something like this by CSS:

[image]

I'm a novice with CSS.

My questions:

- How can I add a green line to the bottom as below? Will I have to add a small `div` under the `div` containing the text and set its background to green? I do know there are many ways to do it but I just want to learn the best practice.
- Is this font Arial?

Comment: Please select an answer if you've received one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either add the div at the bottom as you described, or you can use a border. In either case you'll have some adjustment of heights to do. No big deal.

http://jsfiddle.net/PQgH3/2

```
div {
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
.followers {
    background-color: #777;
    float: right;
    height: 75px;
    color: #ccc;
}
.following {
    background-color: #555;
    float:left;
    height: 70px;
    color: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 5px solid lime;
}

<div class="followers">Followers</div>
<div class="following">Following</div>
```

I don't have the eye to say whether that font is Arial. I can say that it's a similar sans-serif font if it isn't.

Comment: Thank you. The only problem left is just about the font-family. I've tried Arial and Calibri. Both are not exactly the same to my target. Any ideas about the font?

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS sprite sheets. They will help you achieve this effect using images. Generally when you do the markup for the menu use UL and LI tags, then style appropriately for the functionality. Then set it to change the background sprite when the mouse is over then li using the :hover selector. I recommend creating the sprite sheet as an exact image of what you want all the default menu buttons to look like (spanning horizontally). Then do another version below it on the same image that has the look of the hover version. You can repeat this process for any other versions you need like active, disabled, etc. Just make sure you offset the Y value of the background position for each version. Such as this:

```
li { background-position: 0px 0px; }
li:hover { background-position: 0px -100px; }
li:active { background-position: 0px -200px; }
```

Check out this article for a bit more information regarding the markup as well as the design aspect: 
http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-css-menu-using-image-sprites

Edit:
If you don't want to do sprite sheets I have a jsFiddle of pure css3 way of doing it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/uBhKF/

HTML Markup:

```
<ul>
   <li>FOLLOWING</li>
   <li>FOLLOWERS</li>
</ul>
```

CSS3:

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}

li {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #444;
    border-left: 1px dotted #DDD;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #888;
}
li:first-of-type {
    border-left: none;
}
li:hover {
    color: #55E000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #55E000;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

But I couldn't get the font-family right. :(

Comment: I'm not sure why a person would complicate such a simple design with images. What's your reasoning?

Comment: Not much, its just an easier start to beginners. Plus the cross-browser conformity is a bit easier this way. Not all CSS3 effects are going to render the same. If the menu is going to look this simple then I suggest using pure CSS3. But if theres some complicated graphics to it (i.e. shine, textures, gradients) its easier to go with the sprite model. Plus it will cache.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
.header
    {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        height: 102px;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
        width:500px

    }
    .header .header-first
    {
        float: left;

        width: 216px;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #3CA2DF;
    }

    .header .header-last
    {
         width: 216px;
         float:right;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Font is not Arial for sure, i believe its calibri, and try this code for you solution

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="border-bottom: 3px solid #00ff00; 
     background:#000; 
     height: 50px; 
     width:400px; 
     color:#00ff00; 
     text-align:center;">
FOLLOWERS
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also try this

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
td
{
width:400px;
background:#000; 
color:#fff; 
text-align:center;
height: 100px;
font-size:20px;
}
td:hover
{
text-decoration: underline;
border-bottom: 3px solid #00ff00;
color:#00ff00;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="margin:0 auto;">
<tr>
<td>Following</td>
<td>Followers</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```